# Why is my C# 'System.data.sqlclient' not working correctly?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I am creating a Windows 10 Universal App and require the 'data table' functionality, however when I create a `DataTable` object

```
DataTable test = new DataTable();
```

an error occurs

> DataTable does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Also, I have added the namespace using clauses:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

I was wondering if anybody knew how to solve this error?

In addition, when viewing intellisense I cannot see the `SqlDataAdapter` functionality, however, I can see the `SqlDataReader`.

I was wondering if anybody has any insight into these problems?

I am running Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and have Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio installed.

**EDIT**

I don't have a class named `DataTable` and I tried what John Wu said and created the 'var' test variable and I still receive the same error.

Here is the full code for my page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using SQLite.Net;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using System.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace PeriodicTableWin10
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        string ConnectionString = "Connection string goes here";

        private void ShowElement(string ElementName)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand GetElement = new SqlCommand("Select ElementName from tblElement WHERE ElementName=@Element");
                    GetElement.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Element", ElementName));

                    DataTable test = new DataTable();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a class in your app named `DataTable`?

Comment: Hit F12 on `DataTable`, where does it take you?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It takes me to another page called 'DataTable [from metadata] containing a public class called 'DataTable' inside of a namespace called 'System.Data'

Comment: Copy and paste the top section that has comments and put it in your question, it should [look something like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwmok.png)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain This is what i get




**#region Assembly System.Data.Common, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
// C:\Users\Alex\.nuget\packages\System.Data.Common\4.1.0\ref\netstandard1.2\System.Data.Common.dll
#endregion**

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
DataTable test = new DataTable()
```

to

```
var test = new System.Data.DataTable()
```

to ensure you are instantiating the right class.